# If $f_n \leq g$ where g is integrable and $f_n \to f$ then is it true that $\int f \leq \int g $?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Hi I'm just curious as I prepare for a final, I cooked up this problem and wanted to know the answer. Suppose all $f_n>0$ and $f_n \leq g$ for all n and x with g integrable and $f_n \to f$. Then does that imply $\int f \leq \int g$?

I know by dominated convergence that $\int f_n \to \int f$ and $\int f_n \leq \int g_n$ for all n. But I don't know if the inequality holds in the limit as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

$$\int f = \lim_n \int f_n \leq \lim_n \int g = \int g$$

Comment: Shouldn't one assume $f_n$ to be integrable as well?

Comment: @egreg: Definitely. I figured if OP could apply DCT, then the $f_n$ were measurable.

Comment: Yes,sorry they indeed are measurable. We need not assume $f_n$ are integrable though to use dominated convergence and for the integral of f to exist correct?

Comment: @Socchi: Correct.

Comment: thanks! My question was sort of circular though, as if f_n are less than g where g is integrable then without assuming fn are integrable, they clearly are as g is.

Answer (score 2):

Yes: $f_n\leq g$ for all $n$ and $f_n\to f$ implies that $f\leq g$, hence $\int f\leq \int g$.

Comment: ah yes, how dumb of me. thanks